# Eclipse: How to create and load custom key bindings schemes?

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings

I started using [**Eclipse**](http://www.eclipse.org/) recently along with the awesome [**PyDev**](http://pydev.org/) plugin for Python development. Being used to the Visual Studio key bindings, I found that Eclipse has built-in support for a Visual Studio (and Emacs too) key bindings scheme.

However, I would like to **create** my own **custom key bindings scheme** and be able to **load** the scheme into Eclipse. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the [Schemes help page](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/wrkAdv_keyBindings_accelConfig.htm), you can define new Key Schemes through a custom plugin:

> you can define a new type of scheme inside the `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` definition.  The workbench markup that defines the default and emacs key configurations are shown below:

```
<scheme
       name="%keyConfiguration.default.name"
       description="%keyConfiguration.default.description"
       id="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
</scheme>
<scheme
       name="%keyConfiguration.emacs.name"
       parentId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
       description="%keyConfiguration.emacs.description"
       id="org.eclipse.ui.emacsAcceleratorConfiguration">
</scheme>
```

As illustrated by the [Wizard Help Page](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-71.htm), you can export only the key bindings preferences.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/Image266_export_preferences.png))</sub>

And you will be able to import it back through File/Import.

As for the list of shortcuts available depending on your current context:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>: you can check if your modifications apply.